# Show that $res_wF=ord_wf.$ where $F:=f'/f$

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

Let $0\neq f \in \mathbb{V}_k$ und $F:=\frac{f'}{f}$. Show that for all $w \in \mathbb{H}$:
$$res_wF=ord_wf.$$
where $$res_w(F):=\frac{1}{2\pi \mathrm{i}}\int_{|z-w|=\epsilon}F(z)dz$$ is the residue of $F$ in $w$. and $ord_wf$ is the smallest number $r\in \mathbb{Z}$, for which coefficient of the Laurent-Series of $f$ $a_r$ is non-zero. i.e. It's the order of the pole or root. My aim is to prove the $\frac{k}{12}$-Formula for modular forms using the Residue theorem and in the beginning I found this equation, which is not that obvious to me.

Note that $\mathbb{V}_k$ is the Vectorspace of Meromorphic Modular Forms but I am not sure if this is essentiell for the claim.

Comment: Could you explain your notations and give us more context?

Comment: yes sure. I start editing. Sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

F is meromorphic on $\mathbb{H}$ .For a root or pole $w$ of $f$ it is possible to write $f$ as follows: $$f(z)=(z-w)^{ord_wf}\cdot h(z),$$ where $h$ is holomorphic around $w$ and $h(w)\neq0$. It follows 
\begin{align*}
F(z)&=\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}\\
&=\frac{(z-w)^{(ord_f)-1}\cdot ord_wf\cdot h(z)+(z+w)^{ord_wf}\cdot h'(z)}{(z-w)^{ord_wf}\cdot h(z)}\\
&=ord_wf\cdot (z-w)^{-1}+\frac{h'(z)}{h(z)}.
\end{align*}

$$res_wF=res_w \left(\frac{ord_wf}{z-w}+\frac{h'(z)}{h(z)} \right) =res_wf\left( \frac{ord_wf}{z-w} \right)+res_wf \left(\frac{h'(z)}{h(z)} \right).$$
Since $\frac{h'}{h}$ is holomorphic its residue is 0. So
$$res_wF=res_wf\left( \frac{ord_wf}{z-w} \right)=ord_wf.$$